# Enabling "user written scripts" to be processed by the server

Tags: php

I'm currently trying to work out how I would go about enabling the ability for players of my online hacking simulator to write their own scripts defining their own logic to be executed when various conditions are met in my game.

The game is written completely by hand with a few exceptions where I've used Laravels database manager. You can find its open source repository here https://github.com/dialtoneuk/syscrack.

The game is centralised around the idea of software and executing/installing said software. Its an idea I've had for a while but has proven to be more difficult to implement in practice than I originally thought.

I've gone through various different routes such as looking into various PEAR extensions which allow the Lua and JavaScript language to be implemented into PHP with method hooks. But I'm looking for a way to allow the user use data given to define logic and execute various methods which hook to PHP methods.

My intention is to have the finished implementation look something like this

```lua
if( computer.ipaddress != current.ipaddress )
   log( current.computerid, "IP address has connected into my machine:" + computer.ipaddress ) //Method call to PHP method that will do the back end work
```